# How do I configure eclipse (zend studio 6) to hint and code complete several languages?

Tags: zend-studio, code-completion

My dream IDE does full code hints, explains and completes PHP, Javascript, HTML and CSS. I know it exists!

so far, [Zend studio 6](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/features), under the Eclipse IDE does a great job at hinting PHP, some Javascript and HTML, any way I can expand this?

edit: a bit more information: right now, using zend-6 under eclipse, i type in

```
<?php
p //(a single letter "p")
```

and I get a hint tooltip with all the available php functions that begin with "p" (phpinfo(), parse_ini_file(), parse_str(), etc...), each with its own explanation: phpinfo()->"outputs lots of PHP information", the same applies for regular HTML (no explanations however).

However, I get nothing when I do:

```
<style>
b /* (a single letter "b") */
```

I'd love it if I could get, from that "b" suggestions for "border", "bottom", etc. The same applies for Javascript.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the JavaScript and CSS need to be in separate files for this to work.

Example of CSS autocomplete in Eclipse:

Starting to type `border`

> [image: css example in eclipse]

Then setting thickness

> [image: autocompleting border thickness]

Then choosing the color

> [image: autocompleting border color]

Chose red, and it added the ; for me

> [image]

Works pretty good IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The default CSS and HTML editors for Eclipse are really good. The default javascript editor does an OK job, but it needs a little work.

I just tested this in Eclipse 3.3.2

```
function test(){

}

te<CTRL+SPACE>
```

and it completed the method for me as did this:

```
var test = function(){

};


te<CTRL+SPACE>
```

Can you expand on what more you wanted it to do?